# Phonegap3 plugins

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to set up a project with phonegap 3.3.0. I followed the instructions for redownloading the whole with npm and compile and everything works fine. 
I have followed this tutorial.

```
   http://codingsquare.blogspot.com/2013/08/creating-cordova-3-android-project.html
```

Now I want to install the necessary plugins to access device and following the tutorials I see that I need to do with the command ...

```
   cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

This works for me if I create a new project, compile, so I import in eclipse and all is well. But what should be done to an existing project that you want to add the functionality? That to me is not too clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Cordova 3.x, at any time during your development you can add and remove plugins with that command. So say you add the device plugin and build a hello world app. Then tomorrow you want to add the Camera functionality. You can just navigate to the top level app folder and run the cordova commands to add the Camera plugin. Then you can start using this code. When you test, you'll have to rerun the `cordova build` command to copy the code from your "staging area" (the /www/ folder) to the location it needs to be in the mobile app (different for each platform.)

Comment: I have already tried that and I get this message.
Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.

Comment: Oh. You can only add plugins to a cordova project IF that project was initially created with the CLI. So if you have a project from Cordova 2.x, it's unlikely you will be able to add plugins this way. If that is the case, the easiest thing will be for you to just make a new project with the CLI, add the plugins, and copy/paste your code.